# Java Check Json contains sub json

Tags: java, json, contains

Java - I have 2 json data which i am going to get from post and get calls.

How can i verify if Json 1 contains data of Json 2 ?

**Json string 1**

```
[  
    {  
        "name":"John",
        "city":"Berlin",
        "cars":[  
            "audi",
            "bmw"
        ],
        "job":"Teacher"
    },
    {  
        "name":"Mark",
        "city":"Oslo",
        "cars":[  
            "VW",
            "Toyata"
        ],
        "job":"Doctor"
    }
]
```

**Json string 2**

```
   {  
        "name":"John",
        "city":"Berlin",
        "cars":[  
            "audi",
            "bmw"
        ],
        "job":"Teacher"
    }
```

Comment: Your first JSON is a list, while the second is an element of that list. Map them in such a format and perform `list.contains` with `equals` and `hashCode` implementations of mapped objects.

Comment: Where is your attempt? Also, what json library are you using?

Comment: what happens when every field matches except the cars array element, like String 2 has 1 car element but String 1 has 2? what do you expect  in your output then?

Comment: which library do you use for working with json?